# Aligning div at bottom of window innerheight

Tags: jquery, css

I've a header with a height that equals the window's innherheight. This leaves the header's children in the same position as if though the header's height was undefined, though. I want to place a specific child at the bottom of the header, irrespective of its height. Effectively, the div would be at the bottom of the screen until scrolled down. Is there some concise jquery solution for this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('header').css('min-height', windowHeight);
    };
    setHeight();

    $(window).resize(function() {
      setHeight();
    });
});
```

```css
header {background-color:black; width:100%;}
#top {background-color:blue;}
#center {padding:1em; background-color:red;}
#bottom {background-color:green;}
```

```html
<header>
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="center">center</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Add the relevant code mate.

Comment: Updated with code, although the innerheight doesn't seem to be recognized in this snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you have a header tag which height equals to window height. But to help your question you can use,

I'm giving you a solution you can use without js.

set body and html tag height to 100%.

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
}

header {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS or jQuery at all. Here's another solution:

```
header {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This means 100% of the viewer's height. It's a nifty unit in CSS.